# How can I draw/display a text on each corner of two connected line of linerenderer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Square : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;

    private void Start()
    {
        if(lineRenderer == null)
        {
            lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

            lineRenderer.startWidth = 0.3f;
            lineRenderer.endWidth = 0.3f;
        }

        // 0,  0, 0
        // 5,  0, 0
        // 5, -5, 0
        // 0, -5, 0

        Vector3[] positions = new Vector3[4] { new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(5, 0, 0), new Vector3(5, -5, 0), new Vector3(0, -5, 0) };
        DrawSquare(positions);
    }

    void DrawSquare(Vector3[] vertexPositions)
    {

        lineRenderer.positionCount = 4;
        lineRenderer.SetPositions(vertexPositions);
    }
}
```

The result is :

[image: Result]

And this is example of where I want to draw show text as a corner connected two lines marked it with blue circle :

[image: Example of a corner]

And each connected two lines I want to display a text with the coordinates of the connected lines for example 0,0,0 or 0,5,0

Comment: Why voted down ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
using UnityEngine;

public class DrawLines : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public string text;

    private Vector3[] positions;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (lineRenderer == null)
        {
            lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

            lineRenderer.startWidth = 0.3f;
            lineRenderer.endWidth = 0.3f;
        }

        // 0,  0, 0
        // 5,  0, 0
        // 5, -5, 0
        // 0, -5, 0

        positions = new Vector3[4] { new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(5, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(5, -5, 0), new Vector3(0, -5, 0)};
        DrawLine(positions, Color.red, 0.2f);
    }

    void DrawLine(Vector3[] positions, Color color, float duration = 0.2f)
    {
        GameObject myLine = new GameObject();

        myLine.transform.position = positions[0];
        myLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        LineRenderer lr = myLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lr.positionCount = positions.Length;
        lr.startColor = color;
        lr.endColor = color;
        lr.startWidth = 0.1f;
        lr.endWidth = 0.1f;
        lr.useWorldSpace = false;
        lr.SetPositions(positions);
    }

    void DrawText()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < positions.Length; i++)
        {
            var pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(positions[i]);
            text = positions[i].ToString();
            var textSize = GUI.skin.label.CalcSize(new GUIContent(text));
            GUI.contentColor = Color.red;
            GUI.Label(new Rect(pos.x, Screen.height - pos.y, textSize.x, textSize.y), text);
        }
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (positions != null)
        {
            if (positions.Length > 0)
            {
                DrawText();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result :

[image: text]